# MSG command in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, networking

I am unable to send messages to other computers, which are connected through a TP link router.

We can share files, but cannot send a message using the `msg` command. It just shows the message to my laptop only.

Answer (score 1):

The `net send` command has been removed since Vista. So I believe you are referring to Windows `msg` command that is only avaliable on business and ultimate versions of Windows 7. If this is the case then continue reading...

#### Likely solution to resolve the issue is reported: ([*Source*](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/344aa708-5477-46f9-be4f-ad8b3b2348b0))

1. Open the Registry Editor.
2. In the left pane, locate and then click the following registry subkey:

   - **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server`**
3. In the right pane, ensure value of AllowRemoteRPC key is `1`. If not, please change it to `1`.
4. Quit Registry Editor and Reboot the computer.
5. Run MSG command in a elevated CMD window.

Comment: it just sends msg to my self i am using net through DSL which is connected with TP link router, when i use networks it shows all connected computers, files and printers all all also visible but when i use net send at CMD it neither shows nor send any msg to other computers.

Comment: That isn't how this site works. You post questions here. We answer them here too. This site suppose to help every one who might have a similar question.

Comment: I cheched `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server`, the value is one still it sends msg only to me not to other computers. it just sends msg to my self i am using net through DSL which is connected with TP link router, when i use networks it shows all connected computers, files and printers all all also visible but when i use net send at CMD it neither shows nor send any msg to other computers.